# Is there a way around local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error the local variable may not have been initialized on the following line of code

```
final StingBuilder personSearchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.append(getName.getName1(searchOne));
```

I cannot initialize by having final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = null; at first because then I will not be able to change it later so im trying to initialize it final in the instance i need it. It has to be final because if it isnt I get the error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Here is my other class

```
import android.widget.EditText;

public class getName {
static String nameOne = null;
static String nameTwo = null;

static StringBuilder personURLOne = new StringBuilder();
static StringBuilder personURLTwo = new StringBuilder();

public static String personURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=bb0b6d66c2899aefb4d0863b0d37dc4e&query=";

public static StringBuilder getName1(EditText searchOne){
    nameOne = searchOne.getText().toString();


    nameOne = nameOne.replace(" ", "_");


    personURLOne.append(personURL); 
    personURLOne = personURLOne.append(nameOne);



    return personURLOne;

}

public static StringBuilder getName2(EditText searchTwo){
    nameTwo = searchTwo.getText().toString();
    nameTwo = nameTwo.replace(" ", "_");

    personURLTwo.append(personURL);
    personURLTwo = personURLTwo.append(nameTwo);

    return personURLTwo;
}


}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be final? What does the error say when it is not final? Final variables cannot be reassigned. Im not sure the getName class helps us. It would be useful to see the code where the final variable is

Comment: Have you tried initializing as an empty string? ex. `String s = "";`

Comment: As @mah points out, it's nonsense to say `final StingBuilder personSearchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.append(...`, with or without the `final`.  You can't append to something that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`final StingBuilder personSearchURLOne = new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne));`